# Unable to setup Jenkins with GIT

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

I am using a GIT repo on a server trying to setup Jenkins on it.

While trying to add the GIT repository it is giving error

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h ssh+git://amit.sharma@192.169.30.65/opt/repo HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for 192-169-30-65.dsl.beggstelco.net [192.169.30.65] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Done a lot of things but couldn't make it work.
I am using jenkin's own user database.

```
git ls-remote -h ssh+git://amit.sharma@192.169.30.65/opt/repo
```

Above line is getting executed from console successfully.

attaching the test build configuration

[image]

Comment: Is your repository a private repository? If so, don't forget to add a deployment key for Jenkins, so it can actually checkout the code.

Comment: yes it is a private repository. But i am using my user name along with the path and I am using this id from a long time.

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of your project settings?

Comment: added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

## What the error message says

The error message you see above indicates that the SSH connection attempt, which is used for accessing the remote git repository, fails due to a reverse mapping error. This indicates that there is something wrong with the PTR record at `65.30.169.192.in-addr.arpa`. It currently resolves to `192-169-30-65.dsl.beggatelco.net`. Trying to resolve this with your DNS, however, does not provide a valid reply, but fails (NB: This also holds true for me here - so it seems to be a general issue of the admins at beggatelco.net)

For more insight, how you can check this, refer to  http://www.electrictoolbox.com/reverse-mapping-possible-break-in-ssh/

## Most likely the real problem

To me, your entry looks fishy: Do you really want to clone the repo from 192.16**9**.30.65 -- or isn't this just a typo? To me, it looks like that you may want to access another box in your class C private network ([rfc1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918)). Thus, you might have wanted to write 192.16**8**.30.65 instead.